# access to iphone contacts from app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am a new ios programmer and on my app i want to access my contacts for call.Do u guys have any practice documents or tutorial about it.I am looking like on Viber app.When the user click the contact, can call,Sorry my bad english.

Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For displaying contact list you can use the following code:

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
[self presentViewController: picker animated:YES completion: nil];
```

And you can use

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
```

to do the necessary action when selected a phone number from contact.

For a quick start please check [AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/QuickStart.html)